# javascript's onmousemove/ event.clientX is working but throws errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mousemove

I just threw this little mouse tracking example together when I realized, that it throws thousands of errors in the chrome console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

AFAIK this means, that chrome can't find the object that this property belongs to. But if I open the example, it shows the right coordinates perfectly fine. Please help me to get rid of these useless errors.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #tracking {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-size: 300px 300px;
            background-color: #00F;
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mX, mY;
        var track;
        document.onmousemove = update;

        function trackload()
        {
            track = document.getElementById("tracking");
            setTimeout("update()",10);
        }

        function update(e)
        {
            mX = e.clientX;
            mY = e.clientY;
            if (track) {
                track.innerHTML = "X: " + mX + " Y: " + mY + " deg: " + (Math.atan(mY / mX) * (180/Math.PI));
                track.style.cssText = "-webkit-transform: rotate(" + (Math.atan(mY / mX) * (180/Math.PI)) + "deg);";}
            setTimeout("update()",10);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tracking" onclick="trackload()"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the calls to `setTimeout` to prevent the error. It occurs because the `update` function expects an event object, which is not passed in when you call the function through the `setTimeout`. Therefore `e` is undefined, and you get your error.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hPhG/2/).

If there was a good reason for the `setTimeout` calls, you will need to explain it as I can't work out why they are needed at first glance. As a side note, passing a string to `setTimeout` is generally considered bad practice (it's an alias for `eval`). You can just pass a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you just remove the parentheses from your `update` in `setTimeout`, it works and doesn't throw any error in the console.

It should be `setTimeout("update",10)` instead of `setTimeout("update()",10)`.

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`, not the result of one. Even better if it is not a string.